# Problema com syntax mysql

Tags: python, mysql, syntax

I'm constructing a crawler in python and it works well, but at some point i encounter the following syntax error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'), 1, 1, 1, 1, \'1e222a6f2be4477d2d3e8a3f82e0b474.jpg\', \'{\\"inheritFrom\\":\\"1\\",\\\' at line 3')
```

Part of my crawler that is related to this error is:

```
par = '''{"inheritFrom":"1","theme":"","num_leading_items":"2","num_leading_columns":"1","leadingImgSize":"Large","num_primary_items":"4","num_primary_columns":"2","primaryImgSize":"Medium","num_secondary_items":"4","num_secondary_columns":"1","secondaryImgSize":"Small","num_links":"4","num_links_columns":"1","linksImgSize":"XSmall","catCatalogMode":"0","catFeaturedItems":"1","catOrdering":"","catPagination":"2","catPaginationResults":"1","catTitle":"1","catTitleItemCounter":"1","catDescription":"1","catImage":"1","catFeedLink":"1","catFeedIcon":"1","subCategories":"1","subCatColumns":"2","subCatOrdering":"","subCatTitle":"1","subCatTitleItemCounter":"1","subCatDescription":"1","subCatImage":"1","itemImageXS":"","itemImageS":"","itemImageM":"","itemImageL":"","itemImageXL":"","catItemTitle":"1","catItemTitleLinked":"1","catItemFeaturedNotice":"0","catItemAuthor":"1","catItemDateCreated":"1","catItemRating":"0","catItemImage":"1","catItemIntroText":"1","catItemIntroTextWordLimit":"","catItemExtraFields":"0","catItemHits":"0","catItemCategory":"1","catItemTags":"1","catItemAttachments":"0","catItemAttachmentsCounter":"0","catItemVideo":"0","catItemVideoWidth":"","catItemVideoHeight":"","catItemAudioWidth":"","catItemAudioHeight":"","catItemVideoAutoPlay":"0","catItemImageGallery":"0","catItemDateModified":"0","catItemReadMore":"1","catItemCommentsAnchor":"1","catItemK2Plugins":"1","itemDateCreated":"1","itemTitle":"1","itemFeaturedNotice":"1","itemAuthor":"1","itemFontResizer":"1","itemPrintButton":"1","itemEmailButton":"1","itemSocialButton":"1","itemVideoAnchor":"1","itemImageGalleryAnchor":"1","itemCommentsAnchor":"1","itemRating":"1","itemImage":"1","itemImgSize":"Large","itemImageMainCaption":"1","itemImageMainCredits":"1","itemIntroText":"1","itemFullText":"1","itemExtraFields":"1","itemDateModified":"1","itemHits":"1","itemCategory":"1","itemTags":"1","itemAttachments":"1","itemAttachmentsCounter":"1","itemVideo":"1","itemVideoWidth":"","itemVideoHeight":"","itemAudioWidth":"","itemAudioHeight":"","itemVideoAutoPlay":"0","itemVideoCaption":"1","itemVideoCredits":"1","itemImageGallery":"1","itemNavigation":"1","itemComments":"1","itemTwitterButton":"1","itemFacebookButton":"1","itemGooglePlusOneButton":"1","itemAuthorBlock":"1","itemAuthorImage":"1","itemAuthorDescription":"1","itemAuthorURL":"1","itemAuthorEmail":"0","itemAuthorLatest":"1","itemAuthorLatestLimit":"5","itemRelated":"1","itemRelatedLimit":"5","itemRelatedTitle":"1","itemRelatedCategory":"0","itemRelatedImageSize":"0","itemRelatedIntrotext":"0","itemRelatedFulltext":"0","itemRelatedAuthor":"0","itemRelatedMedia":"0","itemRelatedImageGallery":"0","itemK2Plugins":"1","catMetaDesc":"","catMetaKey":"","catMetaRobots":"","catMetaAuthor":""}'''
            plugins = '''{"incptvk2multipleextrafieldgroups":["0"]}'''
            sql = '''INSERT INTO ybis8_k2_categories(`name`, `alias`, `description`,
                    `parent`, `extraFieldsGroup`, `published`, `access`, `ordering`, `image`,
                    `params`, `trash`, `plugins`, `language`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''

prefixo = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(16))
args = (categoria_string, categoria_string, "", cid, 1, 1, 1, 1, prefixo + ".jpg", par, 0, plugins, "*")

cur.execute(sql, args)
```

If you can help me thank you very much : D

Comment: Write in english please, or post your question to http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is written in Portuguese not in English - should be at pt.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also had issues with multiline sql queries as python strings (i.e., queries inside `''' '''` triple quotes like yours). I think this is because of the whitespace involved (line breaks, indentation, etc.) which gets preserved in triple quoted strings. One solution is to have your query as a single line - this is not a great option because it is not pythonic and not readable.

A second option is to group multiple strings together in parentheses:

```
sql = ('INSERT INTO ybis8_k2_categories(`name`, `alias`, `description`, '
       '`parent`, `extraFieldsGroup`, `published`, `access`, `ordering`, `image`, '
       ' `params`, `trash`, `plugins`, `language`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ')
```

Strings within parentheses are automatically concatenated in Python. Note the space at the end of each string too. This is just as easy to read as a multiline string, but has the advantage that it should actually work :)

I know that I probably shouldn't answer this question because it belongs either in English, or on a StackExchange site for your native language, but your problem seemed pretty clear just from the code, and I have wrestled with this issue before so I thought I would give you an answer anyway.